# What's the difference between 检测 and 检查?

Tags: usage, difference

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E6%A3%80%E6%B5%8B) gives "discover" and "detect" for "检测" as well as "examination" and "checking" for "检查".

When talking about COVID-19, should I use 检测 or 检查?

Comment: Please can you provide an example sentence to show how the word would be used when talking about Covid-19?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the difference between the two words is:

> 检测 means "to test"
>
> 检查 means "to inspect" or "to examine", but also "to test" works, in most contexts

When talking about viruses, the two terms are used a bit interchangeably. However you should use 检测 when referring to a diagnostic test:

> 阳性/阴性**检测**结果 positive/negative test results
>
> **检测**冠状病毒的仪器 coronavirus testing devices
>
> 大部分患者尚未进行新冠病毒**检测** most patients have not been tested for the coronavirus

You can use 检查 when you mean "to inspect" or "to test" more generically:

> 对外来人口进行**检查** conduct tests/inspections (generic) on the foreign population
>
> 胸部CT**检查**发现异常 thoracic CT scan shows anomalies
>
> 进行食品安全**检查** conduct food safety inspections

Answer (score 1):

Since COVID-19 was mentioned, I want to share some real-world examples of 检测 being used.  A few weeks ago, here in Beijing there was an outbreak, and we all needed to get tested (检测) for COVID-19.

The first photo is the notice posted outside our building that we should all get tested (I covered up some local information for privacy):

> [image: Notice in our area in Beijing]
>
> **通知**
>
> 居民朋友们，
> 安定们街道将于2020年6月22日（周一）开展全民**核酸检测**，请您携带身份证到社区居委会登记报名。
>
> > **检测**时间：6月22日（具体时间点特定）
> > **检测**地点：？？？
>
> 社区电话：？？？
> 社区地点：？？？
> 报名**检测**的居民参**检**时需配戴好口罩，携带居民身份证及**核酸检测卡**（**检测卡**将于检测前发放）。
> 宝钞南社区2020年6月21日

So when being tested (检测) for COVID-19, we took the nucleic acid test 核酸检测.  And I took a photo of my passport and 核酸检测卡 before getting tested:

> [image: my passport and 核酸检测卡]

Comment: 有「檢查」一下你COVID-19的「檢測」報告嗎？